# SwiftUI Toolbar bottombar background color will not change

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-toolbar

[image]

I'm trying to change the color of my toolbar.
I found the code

```
 .toolbarBackground(Color.blue, for: .navigationBar)
```

and tried to place it in different position in my code but without any success.

here is an example code with my bottombar.
I would like to change the color of my bottom bar

```
truct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar){
                        Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "bag")}
                        Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "dollarsign.circle")}
                        Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")}
                        Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")}
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .toolbarBackground(Color.blue, for: .bottomBar)
        }
    }
  }      
}
```

could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, may I ask, did you eventually find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add:

```
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
```